# Mysql stored procedure cant get the id of the object

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_card`(author       VARCHAR(50),newtext VARCHAR(600),title VARCHAR(200),newSource VARCHAR(2300), username VARCHAR(50), tags VARCHAR(600))
 BEGIN
 DECLARE strLen INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SubStrLen INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cardId INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tagId INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tempTagId INT DEFAULT -1;
DECLARE temp VARCHAR(200);

 INSERT INTO cards (author,text,title,username,source) VALUES   (author,newtext,title,username,newSource);
SET @cardId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Select @cardId;

IF tags IS NULL THEN
SET tags = '';
END IF;

do_this:
LOOP
  SET strLen = CHAR_LENGTH(tags);
SET @temp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 1);

SELECT tagId INTO tempTagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = @temp limit 1;
Select tempTagId;
SELECT tagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = 'ss';

IF tempTagId = -1 THEN
INSERT INTO tag (tagName) VALUES (@temp);
SET @tagId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

select @tagId+10;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cards_tags WHERE tagId = @tagId AND cardId = @cardId) THEN
INSERT INTO cards_tags (tagId,cardId) VALUES (@tagId,@cardId);

Select @cardId;
END IF;
ELSE 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cards_tags WHERE tagId = tempTagId AND cardId = @cardId) THEN
INSERT INTO cards_tags (tagId,cardId) VALUES (tempTagId,@cardId);

select @tagId;
END IF;

END IF;

SET SubStrLen = CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, ',', 1)) + 2;
SET tags = MID(tags, SubStrLen, strLen);

IF tags = '' THEN
  LEAVE do_this;
END IF;
END LOOP do_this;

END
```

It is the damnest thing i have ever seen i guess. I have this stored procedure and in the line 
    SELECT tagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = 'ss';
I am trying to get the id of the object but it is returning 0.
created another stored procedure

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `adds_card`()
BEGIN
DECLARE temp VARCHAR(200);

SET @temp ='ss';
SELECT tagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = @temp;
 END
```

And this returns 3 which is true. Why is the first one returning 0? Driving me really crazy. Spent 5 hours on it and couldnt solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One line in your code is:

```
SELECT tagId INTO tempTagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = @temp limit 1;
```

`@temp` is not defined anywhere, although `temp` is.  So, `@temp` defaults to `NULL` (or to the previous session value) and the `WHERE` clause likely fails.

I strongly recommend prepending local variables with a prefix, so they are not confused with column names.  So I would recommend:

```
SELECT tagId INTO v_tempTagIdFROM tag WHERE tagName = v_temp limit 1;
```

or:

```
SELECT v_tempTagIdFROM := tagId 
FROM tag
WHERE tagName = v_temp 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: in my addcard procedure SELECT tagId FROM tag WHERE tagName = 'ss'; this line actually comes 0. in other one it is 3. they are the same lines. Why is it?

Comment: @mert . . . Because `tagid` is a variable whose value is `0`.  Follow the advice in the answer: prepend *all* variables with a prefix so they are not confused with column names.